# How to pass class name from parent to children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't pass class name from parent to children component. Nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
import React from 'react';
import NavbarItem from './NavbarItem/NavbarItem';
import classes from './NavbarItems.module.scss';

const NavbarItems = (props) => (
    <ul className={classes.NavbarItems}>
        <NavbarItem classname="AboutUs" link="about-us">about us</NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem classname="Services" link="services">services</NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem classname="Gallery" link="gallery">gallery</NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem classname="Contacts" link="contacts">contacts</NavbarItem>
    </ul>
);

export default NavbarItems;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './NavbarItem.module.scss';


class NavbarItem extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render () {
        const {classname, link, children} = this.props;

        return (
            <li className={classes.NavbarItem}>
                <a className={classes.classname} href={link}>{children}</a>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

export default NavbarItem;
```

I'm trying to get a specific class to a tag. I can delete the classes but if I do I can't use specific scss I have for the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get it, you need to add the `className` to anchor tag what you get from the parent. Try this:

```
<a className={classes[classname]} href={link}>{children}</a>
```

Here classes is what you imported from scss file and `classname` is the clas you get in props from parent

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Kinda. Only 3rd item got the class, don't know why.